# What's wrong with following google ecommerce analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have waited for more than 72 hours but ecommerce data is not tracked. Tracking is enabled in the analytics account.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var _gaq = _gaq || [];
       _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-1']);
       _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.welcome.com']);
       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
       _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

       _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
                '650',            // order ID - required
                'bags',  // affiliation or store name
                '19.99',           // total - required
                '0',
                '4.0',           // shipping
                'Anchorage',        // city
                'Alaska',      // state or province
                'USA'
              ]);
        //Add each items in the order
        _gaq.push(['_addItem',
                '650',  // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
                '29',           // SKU/code - required
                'bags set of 4',        // product name
                'Cleaning Supplies',   // category or variation
                '15.99',          // unit price - required
            '1'
              );
        //Now submit the transaction
        _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics server

       (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
        ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
                              'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
       })();
    </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing a closing bracket:

```
//Add each items in the order
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
            '650',  // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
            '29',           // SKU/code - required
            'bags set of 4',        // product name
            'Cleaning Supplies',   // category or variation
            '15.99',          // unit price - required
        '1'
          ]); //right here, missing closing bracket
```

Comment: THanks! Pushed the code with changes. Hopefully,  everything should work now.